# Runge-Kutta-4 Solution for a highly NON LINEAR system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods, nonlinear-dynamics

I recently have been working on models for underwater bubble dynamics which are expressed by highly Non-linear system of ODE's. I have been trying to formulate a numerical method scheme using Runge-Kutta 4th order to match with what is supposedly done in Abaqus for the same model.

I had help from a gentleman on how to formulate the system of ODE's to be Runge-Kutta compatible; i.e $f=y'(t, x1,x2,...xn)$ but I'm having difficult with how to input some other dependent variables for subsequent time steps.

I have sampled a simple similar problem below to describe the complex nonlinearity. Suppose that I have this system of Linear ODE'S (derivatives with respect to  $t$ )

$$x' + y'= 3xy + x'y'- 4t$$

$$y'=y^2 - xt - (x')^2$$

with Initial Conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$.

A very kind gentleman, Dr. Lehmann, helped me formulate the above statement problem to be Runge-Kutta compatible such that: $As'=b$

This is the formulation

**Step 1**: Reduce the system into second order ODE.

**Step2**: Substitute $u$ for $x'$ and $v$ for $y'$ also $u'$ for $x''$ and $v'$ for $y''$

**Step3**: Solve the original system of ODE algebraic to get initial conditions for $u$ and $v$

The formulation becomes

$$u+v-uv=3xy-4t\\u^2+v=y^2-xt$$
for $u$ and $v$ for given $t_0,x_0,y_0$, select one of the 4 solutions.

$$\pmatrix{1-v& 1-u\\2u&1}\pmatrix{u'\\v'}=\pmatrix{3uy+3xv-4\\2yv-ut-x}$$

input $[x,y,u,v]$, output $[u,v,u',v']$. Check for sign changes in the determinant, avoid division by zero.

The issue I'm facing is
The system of ODE in the form of $As'=b$, has dependent variables $u$, $v$, $x$, $y$ and $t$. But from solving the system of linear equations $As'=b$ through RK4, the only output is
$u'$ and $v'$, which means that, in a RK4 algorithm, I can only do the first time step using the initial conditions for $[x(0), y(0), u(0) ,v(0)]$ with the only output $[u', v']$. my code can not perform a second time step because I don't have update for $x$ and $y$

How can I get an output from the first time step so that I can get an update for second time step  $x(0+h)$ and  $x(0+h)$

Much thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Your original system can be reduced to the form $x'=f_1(x,y,t),y' = f_2(x,y,t)$ with the help of two MATHEMATICA commands `sols = Solve[{dx + dy == 3 x y + dx dy - 4 t, dy == y^2 - x t - dx^2}, {dx, dy}]; {x'[t] == dx, y'[t] == dy} /. sols[[1]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @Cesareo : You also need a mechanism that guarantees that always the same solution branch is chosen. This might be locally true, but globally the decisions on signs might change.

Comment: The state in my approach always has dimension 4. That the second derivatives are computed via a linear system is no obstacle to composing the 4 dimensional derivatives vector.

Comment: @LutzLehmann : For a given system above; the second derivatives yields the changed variables first order derivative, How should I  factor out a 4 -first order derivatives as s'... The RK4 scheme limits to  Un+1 and Vn+1 from u' and v'.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks for the remark. Indeed the solution can have three branches.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Would you help to show me how I could construct a 4-dimensional derivatives  vector from the formulation above?

Comment: @Cesareo Thank you for your input. I will check out this alternative as well.

Comment: I used the method of "STATE VARIABLE" I realized that, unlike the traditional change of variable for second order ODE's to make them Runge-Kutta compatible (where the original variable is still retained in the vector of variables of derivative) here, all original variables are replaced and therefore I would not obtain the original solution. in terms of x and y but rather instead of u and v.